# Taylor's theorem and the behaviour of the error as $x \rightarrow a$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand the motivation part of the Wikipedia article(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Motivation)

This article tells us that $R_{1}=f(x)-P_{1}(x)=h_{1}(x)(x-a)$  "goes to zero a bit faster then $(x-a)$

Similiarly we have,

$R_{2}=f(x)-P_{2}(x)=h_{2}(x)(x-a)^2$  "goes to zero a bit faster then $(x-a)^2$"

This is supposed to be because of the  limiting behaviour of $h_{i}$. Could someone spell this out for me please?

To me we get that $(x-a) < \delta$ gives $h_{i}(x) < \epsilon$ but I dont see how that gives us that the right hand side of the above equalites have the claimed properties. So why does these "goes to zero a bit faster then $(x-a)^n?$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(x-a) \longrightarrow 0$ as $x \longrightarrow a$, we must have that the product $h_1(x)(x-a)$ is even smaller than $(x-a)$ as $x \longrightarrow a$ (the limiting behaviour of $h_1$ stated there, h has to get much smaller than 1 when $x$ approaches $a$).  That's what is meant by "$h_1(x)(x-a) \longrightarrow 0$ faster than $(x-a) \longrightarrow 0$ as $x \longrightarrow a$"

Comment: ah  so just that $h <1$, somewhere, if we wanted to, is in some sense the essence?

Comment: Yes, $h$ get smaller than 1, but then also still smaller than any $p<1$ as well. Because $h$ by itself is getting close to zero even as $x-a$ is.  So, it gets smaller that $x-a$, then smaller than $0.5 (h-a)$, then smaller than $0.1 (x-a)$, then smaller than $0.01 (x-a)$ and so on. So...much smaller.

Comment: I dont understand the significane of being faster to $0$ then $x-a$. I understand that we can get arbitrarly close to tbe function value by moving close to $x$ using the approximation, but what does $a-x$ have to do with that?